# Sort table values using table sorter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I need to sort the table values that was dynamically added into a empty table.

But,I can able to sort the table when table already contain a value in it before a dynamic value is added to the table.In this sorting the both existing value and added value is sorted.
Which works as expected. But it doesn't works when a value added dynamically to a empty table.

Please help me. thanks in-advance.
Code given below.

```
$("#List").append("<tr><td class='col-medium '>" + $('#Text_FirstName').val().trim() +"</td>" +
    "<td class='col-medium '>" + $('#Text_LastName').val().trim() + "</td>" +
    "<td class='col-large '>" + $('#Text_Email').val().trim() + "</td>" +"</tr>");
    $('#List').tablesorter();
    $('#List').trigger('update');
```

Comment: Are you triggering an "update" on the table ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update))? If you are, and it still isn't working, please share the code you are using.

Comment: @Mottie : Thanks for reply.
Yes,I have tried using $('#table').trigger('update') also.Then also it is not working while adding a data dynamically into a empty table

Comment: @Mottie : Please find the code that i have updated in my question. Thanks

Comment: That should work. Although the `$('#list').tablesorter()` doesn't do anything, so remove it - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2349/)

Comment: @Mottie : Thanks Mottie it worked for me after i integrated your code in mine. Thanks once again.